# Automatic Git web deployment when pushing

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up a git repo that follows our current configuration and not finding what I'm looking for on Google.

I'd like to set up our repo to point to a directory that is used as the base directory of our web server so when something is pushed to the "develop" branch it's added and can be viewed from our development server immediately.

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `post-receive` hook and `checkout` the contents to your document root. This should do the trick.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$refname" == "refs/heads/develop" ]; then
  GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/dev git checkout -f
fi
```

Comment: that's exactly it.. here is a good article explaining the full process. http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto